# PHP $_SESSION variables single page

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm trying to update session variables via some anchor tags to keep track of information to display. I currently am using `$_GET` variables, but would like to keep a clean address bar as this is a single page app. What I can't figure out is how to update the session variable and have it refresh the page and update the variable.

This is the only way I can think to do it, but it's not working as I expected.

Use a `click.php` file that grabs the `$_GET` variable and applies it to a session variable and redirects back to the `index.php` file.

**index.php**

```
<a href="click.php?msv=PhotoCount" >Photo Count</a>
```

**click.php**

```
if ( !empty($_GET['msv']) ) {
  $msv = $_GET['msv'];
  $_SESSION['meta'] = $msv;
  header('Location: /');
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) on that page? If not, place it after `<?php` in your `click.php` file.

Comment: *Ditto* on `session_start();` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should start the php session explicitly at the beginning of both `index.php` and `click.php`, like this .. only then your session data will persist

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

If you choose to do it, consider removing session data later using this snippet

```
<?php session_destroy(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of index.php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['msv']) && !empty($_GET['msv'])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['msv'] = $_GET['msv'];
  }
?>
```

and give the target location of the link to the same page. So, there is no need of the second page.

If you are to use both the pages, give the target location of the link to the second page and add the this line at the end of the if statement.

```
header('Location: /index.php');
```